# How to define a custom property in shape key?

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I need to set a custom property inside the shape key class.

```
        bpy.types.ShapeKey.groups = bpy.props.StringProperty()
```

But when I try to change its value, raises me an error:

```
context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[1].groups = "asdas"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ShapeKey' object attribute 'groups' is read-only
```

How can I solve this?